# How to make drawable animation with sprite in Andengine?

Tags: android, andengine

I was trying to make an animation like drawable_animation  but is hard to find Andengine "clean" information. So i have a sprite an i want it to change its current texture region to another ,wait some time ,then to another etc. And while doing this move to the right. I could use `sprite.setx(sprite.getx+movement);` but i belive it is not the proper way, so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `AnimatedSprite` class in andEngine that takes care of animation of the sprite. There is a lot of tutorials:
http://andenginedevtutorial.blogspot.com/2012/11/animated-sprite-andengine-gles2-tutorial.html
or 
http://stuartmct.co.uk/2012/07/18/andengine-the-basics-of-sprites/

What you need to prepare is a tiled sprite - a png file containing all the frames of the animation distributed evenly in the picture.

Comment: Cant i use different textureRegions?

Comment: There is no method inside sprite class to do that. But there was a way some time ago to change a sprite class inside andengine package and add setter for itextureregion. But you should avoid that.

Comment: Does it matter if my png containing all the frames is not power of 2

Comment: I think that it does not. Atlas have to be power of two, not region

Comment: So i must create (manually) a png with evenly distribured frames. And then add it  to an Atlas to then remove the "sticker" and say "x colums and y rows" and  atach it to the AnimatedSprite. Right?

Comment: More or less;-) since you probably already have sprites you just need to connect them into one. AnimatedSprite or TiledSprite will be easy to use

Comment: one quick thing how do i chose wich frames to put while animatig and wich by default(while not animating)

Comment: Check the end of the second link. 'Sprite.animate()' method is responsible for animating sprite, choosing which frames and how long will be presented. For choosing frames individually without animation use TiledSprite method

Comment: Second link is dead, seems to be a server test page.